# php html ограничить ввод времени <24:00 на интерфейсе

Tags: php, html, laravel

Всем привет нужно сделать так чтобы в интерфейсе нельзя было вводить время больше 23:59.
Пробовал через `type='time' max='23:59'` но это браузерозависимое решение(на разных браузерах работает по разному). Нужно не браузерозависимре решение.

Можно ли сделать и как?

Comment: можно сделать на  js проверку на ввод времени

Comment: это со стороны клиента идет проверка или со стороны сервера?

Comment: По правильному у вас должна быть на js проверка, а потом уже на сервере (laravel в данном случае)

Comment: Ну на стороне сервера обязательно. Или регулярным посложнее. Или, если слабоват, простую регулярку на соответствие формату, а потом какой-нибудь explode. А на клиенте разве удобно время вручную с двоеточием вбивать? Может какое-нибудь выпадающее меню сделать с выбором часов и минут? Тогда на клиенте ничего проверять не надо будет.

Comment: у меня задача такая со стороны клиента ограничить ввод времени больше 23:59 что бы на сервер не пошли не валидные данные

Comment: На сервере в любом случае надо проверять. На клиенте можно стандартными возможностями воспользоваться и отправить часы и минуты по отдельности. Если кто-то обошел интерфейс, это его проблемы